# How to rename a MSSQL Database that has name "Database"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a MSSQL Database named "Database". Now when I am trying to rename it using query shown below,

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE Database
Modify Name = Database01
GO
```

It gives me this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'Database'.

But this query works fine for other database. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try brackets around the second "Database"

Comment: ya it works. but why i have to place brackets? what is the logic behind this. i mean all other database just works fine so what logic makes it exceptional? @logixologist

Comment: Database is a reserved word, meaning SQL uses it. I suppose if you wanted to call your database SELECT you could probably do that too if you put the brackets around it like this: [SELECT]. Not recommended though because names need to make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you "quote" the table name it should work. The default quote characters are square brackets [], so:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Database]
Modify Name = Database01
GO
```

Comment: because Database is a reserved word (DATABASE is the same as Database), and it is generally a very, very, very bad idea to use reserved words for database names

Comment: @Rezoan - Basically, unless you quote the db name, the server has no idea if you mean the command Database, or the db name Database.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the the Long code you Can just use the System built-in Stored Procedure -`sp_renamedb'oldDBName','NewDBName'`

Answer (score 0):

when you have to use reserved keywords for table name,database name,column name always put [] (big brackets )

such as

`select * from [Table]` in place of `select * from table`

`select [column] from [table]` in place of `select column from table`

but its very bad idea to put reserved keyword as a name for your objects.